# If I generate HTML elements using append, can I affect them using jQuery after that?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I used the `append` method in jQuery to generate some HTML input boxes; now I want to make some effects on those input elements using jQuery but I can't. This is a little example of what I wanna do.

```
 <style type="text/css"></style>
 <style>
 .focus
 {
   background-color: green;
 }
 </style>
 <script src="alu_afric/Java/java.js"></script>
 <script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    $("#newHTML").append('<input type="text" placeholder="some text .."/>');
  });
  $("input").focus(function() {
    $(this).addClass("focus");
  });
});
 </script>
 <button>Click</button>
<body>
<div id="newHTML"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: You could just have a `input:focus {
    background-color: green;
}` in the css, then you have no need to worry about jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The event listener should be

```
$( document ).on( 'focus', 'input[type=text]', function() {
```

Instead of

```
$("input").focus(function(){
```

Please check snippet for more understanding.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("#newHTML").append('<input type = "text" placeholder = "some text .."/>');
  });
  $( document ).on( 'focus', 'input[type=text]', function() {
    $(this).addClass("focus");
  });
});
```

```css
.focus
 {
   background-color: green;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Click</button>
<body>
  <div id = "newHTML"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: thanks for answering but it gives me the same result

Comment: The So should have to use $( document ).on( 'focus', 'input[type=text]', function() { event listener instead of $("input").focus(function(){

Comment: @M-AmrMoussa have you checked updated answer?

Comment: thanks man that saved my life !!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. As long as you append html first then bind the event you want for it.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
//for safe calling lets add a class
    $("#newHTML").append('<input type = "text" placeholder = "some text .." class="inpt-class"/>');
  //after the input is add to the page add an event for it
  // either use or .on() or .focus()
  $("input.inpt-class").focus(function(){
    $(this).addClass("focus");
  });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use the `appendTo` method instead you can store your input-element in a variable and make changes to it.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style = "txt/css"></style>
 <style>
 .focus
 {
   background-color: green;
 }
 </style>
 <script src = "alu_afric/Java/java.js"></script>
 <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    var input = $('<input type = "text" placeholder = "some text .."/>');
    input.appendTo("#newHTML");
    input.css('background', 'red');
  });
  $("input").focus(function(){
    $(this).addClass("focus");
  });
});
 </script>
 <button>Click</button>
<body>
<div id = "newHTML"></div>
</body>
```